# How to fetch Html text or element in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I'm new at Reactjs and I try to fetch some HTML data but my problem is when I check browser the HTML tag show as a text, not as an element

My component source:

```
import React from 'react';

export class About extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            data: '<p>Hello world</p>',
        }
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div className="container">
                {this.state.data}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

the result it shows:

```
<p>Hello world</p>
```

what I want to see:

Hello world

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html), if you receive the html as string..

Change

```
<div className="container">
   {this.state.data}
</div>
```

to

```
<div className="container" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: this.state.data }} />
```

Component would be like,

```
class About extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      data: "<p>Hello world</p>"
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div
        className="container"
        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: this.state.data }}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

> [**Working Example here...**](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-basic-class-component-3fo99)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html) at your own risk (you should use a sanitizer to protect yourself from XSS.)

Comment: should be a comment.